# Stop parent function or method in JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, methods

I have the following code:

```
$("#add-button").click( function(add_color) {

    $.each( $("input[name='color[]']"), function () {

        if( color_selected == $(this).val() )
        {
            alert( "Color already choosen" );
            return false;
        }

    });

    alert("Here is the end of add-button");

});
```

I need to stop the code if return false is called, but the JQuery is stopping only the $.each method.

I used "Event.stop(add_color)" instead of "return false" and it works, but i don't know if this is correct.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always do this:

```
$("#add-button").click( function(add_color) {
    var doIStop = false;
    $.each( $("input[name='color[]']"), function () {

        if( color_selected == $(this).val() )
        {
            alert( "Color already choosen" );
            doIStop = true;
        }

    });
    if(doIStop) {
        return false;
    }
    alert("Here is the end of add-button");
});
```

Event.stop is usually okay, though.

Comment: i used the solution with the boolean flag, it works fine. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. I'd appreciate it if you marked this answer as the solution.